# Soft Close Hidden Hinges for Lipped (Rabbeted) Cabinet Doors?

Tags: hinges

I have old oak cabinets in the kitchen and looking to make some upgrades. Doors are lipped/rabbeted and partial overlay. Cabinets are face frames.

I’m struggling to find options for soft close hidden hinges that aren’t $20/hinge (Rockler makes the Salice only ones I’ve found so far, but they are also only 110deg). Regular soft close hinges for partial overlay or inset won’t work because of the rabbet interfering with opening and closing.

I’ve looked into maybe trying some 170 degree soft close frameless hinges from Blummotion and putting blocking in, but not sure if that will work (may order a pair to try). Has anybody done/seen this?

I suppose another option is to build out the cabinet doors with strips around the edge to fill in the rabbet but that is a lot of work. Or just get all new cabinet doors, but I hate wasting all that wood.

Images of cabinets: https://imgur.com/a/MjlKKKe

Comment: I would suggest that this be migrated to [woodworking.se]. There are probably more folk there who would have good suggestions than here.

Comment: Is soft-close a dealbreaker? Given the constraints I was reasonably confident this wouldn't be possible without mods, and your third para pretty much is exactly what I was thinking might work.

Comment: *"Or just get all new cabinet doors, but I hate wasting all that wood."* If you're a woodworker the wood doesn't have to go to waste. If you're not you could sell them on CL or Marketplace to recoup a small bit of the replacement cost. The wood isn't exactly prime material for repurposing due to the dimensions, but it is solid hardwood and there's always potential there — the doors could make a whole bunch of shallow trays or small boxes, provide parts for workshop jigs etc. Plus, always a chance someone else might be able to use them as-is.